# MCMC predict volatility with GARCH

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, garch

This is using MCMC (MH) algo to predict volatility from GARCH model:

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/machine-learning-for/9781492085249/ch04.html

For simplication, consider (0,10)-GARCH (only consider vol) and a trained GARCH gives you a linear relation between variances (understand as Markov states?). I cannot think out how to use MCMC then? As I understand, MCMC is used to generate samples for a given distribution which is regard as the stationary distribution of a Markov chain.

From the code, seems MCMC is used as a metric to adjust GARCH, the main prediction model is still GARCH.

[image]

Comment: Please post code as text (formatted as code) rather than a picture. Thank you.